# ExecuteExcel4Macro to get range/charts from closed workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, adodb, excel-4.0

I use these lines to get values from closed workbooks:

```
Arg = "'" & Path & "[" & File & "]" & Sheet & "'!" & "R4C4"  
Arg = CStr(Arg)
GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Arg)
```

Is there another way than loop to get values from a range? The loop solution is working, but it would be clearer if I could get the range directly with `ExecuteExcel4Macro`. I've tried to input a range in `Arg`, but it returns an error.

I have the same question for charts, how can I get them? My solution for the moment consists of getting values and replotting the charts. It works, but I would be happier with a `GetChart(Chartname)` function.

I've seen that I can use ADODB connection to get value from closed workbooks. But it was a little too complex compared to `ExecuteExcel4Macro`. Would it be easier to use ADODB connection in the case of range/charts?

Comment: there is no practical way to extract a chart from a closed workbook-much simpler to open and copy it if you need to!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following bit of code pulls info from a range in a closed workbook and copies it in the same ranges in the Active Workbook:

```
    Sub GetRange()
        With Range("A1:D50")                                    'set range to copy from / to.
            .Formula = "='C:\E3_Test\[CC_Data.xlsx]AllData'!A1" 'refers to a workbook, sheet and first cell.
                                                                'It will put the relative references into the target sheet correctly.
            .Value = .Value                                     'changes formula to value.
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why not range.formula = " [...] " ? and why .value=.value ?

Comment: @Imorin The `.formula` takes the reference as the top corner of the data to copy. The `Range` at the start is the area in which the data is copied to, putting relative referenced formulas into the cells.  The `.value=.value` line forces the cell content to be the values of the formulas, rather than the formulas themselves.

Comment: I always use `.Formula = .Value` instead of `.Value = .Value`.  The latter can cause inconsistencies between the two ranges in certain situations.  Annoyingly, since I figured out that fix I've forgotten what problem it solved.  There is a very good chance it involved international date formats, which frequently misbehave whenever VBA is involved.  The issue was however definitely real and was still in existence as late as Excel 2007 SP3.

Comment: okay it works but what if you want the result in an array and not a Range ?