# Get data from another existing workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry, I am new to VBA, I google a lot but I just can't find how to get the data from other Excel to destination Excel.

Example:

[image]

[image]

First one is my target excel.

Second one is my destination excel.(where I write the VBA macro)

```
Dim WB1 As Workbook
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Darren\Documents\Excel\test2.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True
Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
```

I open the Excel but I don't know how to get the value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ExecuteExcel4Macro to get range/charts from closed workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981081/executeexcel4macro-to-get-range-charts-from-closed-workbooks)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Dim WB1 As Workbook
Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\Darren\Documents\Excel\test2.xlsx", _
                         UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
WB1.Range("A1").Currentregion.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

If you perform the steps you want to do while recording a macro, that will give you a starting point for your code.

Comment: I wonder MySql can do almost same stuff that VBA can do?

Comment: I just want to pick some column and compare whether they are same

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt have to be VBA right? This can often be much to complicated. if you only want to get data from one excel to another you could use power query.
Go to DATA tab -> Get & Transform data area -> Get Data dropdown -> From File -> From Workbook.
[image]