# compatibility error when pulling data from closed xls file

Tags: excel, vba

When I pull data from the closed file, it gives a compatibility error in some xls files. How can I get past this error. It happens when I open the xls Excel file and say Convert Compatibility Section in the File>Info menu. I want to do this without opening the file.

Or I want to convert the Excel file directly to xlsx.

Thank you

I did not say Application.DisplayAlerts = False to turn off the warnings when pulling data from the closed file. It does not pull the data.

Some of the codes I used

```
Set cn = CreateObject("adodb.connection")
Set Rs = CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
cnstr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ExcelDosyaYolu & ExcelDosyaAdi & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=NO"""
cn.Open (cnstr)

Set oRS = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)
Do While Not oRS.EOF
   sSheetName = oRS.Fields("table_name").Value
   aaa = sSheetName
   oRS.MoveNext
Loop



    s1 = "[Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=NO;Database=" & ExcelDosyaYolu & ExcelDosyaAdi & "].[" & aaa & "]"

    Sorgu = "select F1,F2,F3,F4,F5   from " & s1 & " where F5 is not null and F5 not like 'T%' and F5 not like 'Özel İşlem Açıklamam'"
Set Rs = cn.Execute(Sorgu)
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16981578/11318818) or tried to follow this [Copy a range from closed workbooks (ADO)](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win024.htm) solution for using ADO?